# How to change part of a MKV video with another MKV video without re-encode and without changing audio file in that primary MKV file

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, encoding

I have a lecture that I have recorded with using OBS studio and my microphone

But I want to replace certain part of that video with another video without re-encoding or touching the audio

The another video is also recorded with OBS studio with the same settings

If encoding is necessary I accept that as well

So what would be the appropriate `ffmpeg` command?

Here the files to give more clear example

- a.mkv : 77 minutes long
- b.mkv : same format and 2 minutes long
- c.mkv : I want to replace 00.23.00 - 00.25.00 part of a.mkv with     -  - b.mkv without changing the audio file of a.mkv

Is this possible without encoding or with re-encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) to delay the timestamps and the [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) filter to layer the video. Audio is [stream copied](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) and therefore untouched.

## overlay at beginning

Example to overlay `b.mkv` over `a.mkv` starting from the beginning:

```
ffmpeg -i a.mkv -i b.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=eof_action=pass[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output.mkv
```

## start overlay at certain timestamp

Example to overlay `b.mkv` over `a.mkv` starting at 00:23:00 (23 minutes):

```
ffmpeg -i a.mkv -i b.mkv -filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS+23*60/TB[bvideo];[0:v][bvideo]overlay=eof_action=pass[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output.mkv
```

## Same as above, but limit overlay duration

This only shows 0-30 seconds from `b.mkv` starting at 00:23:00 (23 minutes):

```
ffmpeg -i a.mkv -i b.mkv -filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS+23*60/TB[bvideo];[0:v][bvideo]overlay=eof_action=pass:enable='lte(t,30)'[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output.mkv
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have few questions about the durations. So this is the duration of first input "23*60" .  this is the duration of second video "TB[2m]" but what is this? [0:v][2m] . how do I set the beginning time of overlaying?

Comment: I tested like this and it failed. ffmpeg -i a.mkv -i b.mkv -filter_complex "[1:v]setpts=PTS+5843/TB[110];[0:v][0]overlay=eof_action=pass[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output.mkv. I want to appliy 110 seconds file starting from first second to 5843 seconds file

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG setpts is what you use to set the beginning time of overlaying. It is **not** the duration of the first input. In my example `23*60` = 23 * 60 seconds = 1380 seconds = 23 minutes = the desired time you mentioned in the question when you wanted the overlay to begin. `[2m]` is just an arbitrary label I gave to the output from setpts. You could name it anything such as `[mydelayedvideotobeoverlaid]`.

Comment: this is what I call an answer. Thank you very much. That 2m is a bit confusing though I think you should name it like "variable_temp_name". so in the first part of ; you compose a variable with 2m and use that variable at the second part of the command right?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG I renamed it `[bvideo]` which is hopefully less confusing. Yes, you name the output(s) from a filter so it can be used by other filters or directly to output file. See [FFmpeg Filtering Introduction](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) for an illustrated example.